# Differentiation of a series of increasing functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hi,

Let $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of increasing functions defined on an interval, say $[0,1]$.

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges for all $x \in [0,1]$. Let $f:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$.

It is well known that an increasing function defined on an interval is differentiable almost everywhere on that interval. But is it true that

$$f'(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n'(x)$$
almost everywhere on $[0,1]$?

Any reference would help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see Theorem 4.1 on p. 177 of [this book](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=5ddbKSkaL8EC&pg=PR8&lpg=PR8&dq=%2522differentiating+series+of+monotone+functions%2522&source=bl&ots=_L6toIMGqu&sig=oTTRArrbAIjIKSFBRs6Egb819Ts&hl=iw&ei=IWYjTbK0BYGyhAfOnby3Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%2522differentiating%2520series%2520of%2520monotone%2520functions%2522&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

This is also Theorem 17.18 (page 267) of *Real and Abstract Analysis* by Hewitt and Ross. The result is credited there to Fubini.